# Insert with Linq-to-SQL an object determined through reflection

Tags: linq-to-sql, reflection

I am trying to populate a row in a table given a key value list

Using DataContext.Mapping I am able to locate the correct table (given a table name) and create a row.

```
// Look up the table
        MetaTable matchedTable = null;

        foreach (MetaTable tableMetaData in db.Mapping.GetTables())
        {
            if (table.Equals(tableMetaData.TableName))
            {
                matchedTable = tableMetaData;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (matchedTable == null)
        {
            throw new Exception("Invalid table name specified");
        }
```

I then iterate over the row properties and populate the values.

```
// Iterate through the dictionary and try to match up the keys with column names
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> listItem in list)
        {
            PropertyInfo propertyInfo = rowType.GetProperty(listItem.Key);

            if (propertyInfo == null)
            {
                throw new Exception("Invalid column name specified");
            }

            // Set the value on the object
            try
            {
                propertyInfo.SetValue(row, Convert.ChangeType(listItem.Value, propertyInfo.PropertyType), null);
            }
            catch
            {
                throw new Exception("Value specified cannot be converted to database type");
            }
        }
```

I now need to get this row object inserted back into the DB. I have been playing around with `db.GetTable<rowType>();` with no luck. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was overthinking it

```
db.GetTable(rowType).InsertOnSubmit(row);
db.SubmitChanges();
```